# How to return results where one related field exists, but another does not?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this, but I can't even think of how to accurate describe what it is I want to do, so I can't Google it. My actual scenario is slightly more complicated than this, but a very basic version would be having two separate tables - one showing the names and dates of people who bought tickets for the bus, and another showing the names and dates of people who travelled on the bus, like so

```
tableTicket                tableTravel

custName    ticketDate      custName    travelDate
--------    ----------      --------    ----------
tim         01-jul-15       tim         01-jul-15
tim         03-jul-15       tim         02-jul-15
anna        15-jul-15       tim         03-jul-15
anna        16-jul-15       anna        15-jul-15
anna        20-jul-15       anna        16-jul-15
emily       02-jul-15       rob         07-jul-15
rob         07-jul-15       rob         12-jul-15
rob         12-jul-15       rob         13-jul-15
```

I want to return only the names and dates of people who travelled without a ticket, but not those who bought a ticket and didn't travel. So I would want to return Tim's journey on 02-jul-15, but not emily's unused ticket on 02-jul-15.

The problem I'm having is that I can't just look for dates that appear is travelDate that don't appear in ticketDate, because then it will match tim's journey with emily's ticket.

I presume that the best way to do this would be with joins, but I'm not sure how. If I join on custName, it creates a row where tim buys a ticket and travels on 01-jul-15 (which is fine) but also creates a row where he bought a ticket on 01-jul-15 and travels on 02-jul-15.

Ideally, I think I want to end up with a table like this, but I've got no idea how to get there

```
custName    ticketDate      travelDate
--------    ----------      --------    
tim         01-jul-15       01-jul-15
tim         NULL            02-jul-15
tim         03-jul-15       03-jul-15
anna        15-jul-15       15-jul-15
anna        16-jul-15       16-jul-15
anna        20-jul-15       NULL
emily       02-jul-15       NULL
rob         07-jul-15       07-jul-15
rob         12-jul-15       12-jul-15
rob         NULL            13-jul-15
```

I could then select all rows where `ticketDate IS NULL` and it would give me the details of the journeys that Tim and Rob took without a ticket.

Apologies if I'm barking up entirely the wrong tree. I'm sure it's something really easy, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Kindly provide us create  and insert statements

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that - the database I've put in above doesn't actually exist, I just made it up as it's a clearer way of explaining what I wanted to do than if I used the actual database I'm using, which is full of all sorts of other gumpf.

Comment: You explained clearly . To test our query we need DDL and insert statement.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I don't know what you mean by that. (I'm very new at this)

Comment: @themightyshrub No one is going to help you unless you provide data for us to test.  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Eric I've read that guide - do you mean you need the tables I've put above written in a different way? I don't know how to do that - all the tables I'm using at the moment are prebuilt and I only have read access, so I have no idea how to create/add/edit existing tables. If you could please explain what kind of data it is that you need, perhaps with an example, then I will do my best to get it for you, but as I've already stated, I'm VERY new at SQL, and coding in general, so whilst I'm trying my best, I don't have the knowledge to know how to answer some of these questions.

Comment: @themightyshrub Provide some insert statements so that people can just easily copy and paste the data.  For example, `CREATE TABLE tableTicket(custName VARCHAR(250), ticketDate DATETIME)`. `INSERT INTO tableTicket(custName, ticketDate) VALUES('tim', '2015-07-01')`.  Some valid data that people can just paste and execute.

Comment: @Eric thank you, that makes sense. I’d presumed it would be something simple people could just look at and say “oh, do this”, but I can see it would be easier if it can be tested. I’m out if the office now, but will read up on INSERT and CREATE TABLE tonight, and get the code up first thing in the morning. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems want `FULL OUTER JOIN` :

```
select coalesce(tk.custName, tr.custName) as custName, tk.ticketDate, tr.travelDate
from tableticket tk full outer join
      tabletravel tr
      on tr.custname = tk.custname and tr.travelDate = tk.ticketDate;
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! I'd tried outer join before, but I didn't realise you could join on more than one column, and I'd not heard of coalesce. Thank you for the clear response :)

Comment: @themightyshrub. . . `Coalesce()` is similar one with `isnull()` in `SQL Server`.

Comment: @themightyshrub. . . However, `coalesce()` function is ANSI SQL Standard which could work in almost all DBMS.